# LaunchedEffect() cannot be relaunched

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

Read this `LaunchedEffect take a variable number of keys as a parameter that are used to restart the effect whenever one of those keys changes.`  from [here](https://developer.android.com/codelabs/jetpack-compose-advanced-state-side-effects?authuser=1&continue=https%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.android.com%2Fcourses%2Fpathways%2Fcompose%3Fauthuser%3D1%23codelab-https%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.android.com%2Fcodelabs%2Fjetpack-compose-advanced-state-side-effects#3).

I am trying it out by changing the key and check if the LaunchEffect would be relaunched.

Here is my code:

```
private const val SplashWaitTime: Long = 2000

@Composable
fun LandingScreen(modifier: Modifier = Modifier, onTimeout: () -> Unit) {
    Box(modifier = modifier.fillMaxSize(), contentAlignment = Alignment.Center) {
        val currentOnTimeout by rememberUpdatedState(onTimeout)
        var key = 1
        LaunchedEffect(key) {
            Log.w("xx", "Launched effect is running key = $key")
            delay(SplashWaitTime)
            key = 2
            currentOnTimeout()
        }
        key = 3
        Image(painterResource(id = R.drawable.ic_crane_drawer), contentDescription = null)
    }
}
```

With code above, running the app, and I can see there is only one log print in the Logcat.

Which is:

`2022-05-08 18:42:35.951 20101-20101/androidx.compose.samples.crane W/xx: Launched effect is running key = 3`

So questions are:

1. How can I ensure the LaunchEffect can be run with key = 1 first? And then make it relaunch with key = 3.
2. Why key = 2 won't trigger LaunchEffect being relaunched?

Update:

[image]

My Android Studio:

```
Android Studio Chipmunk | 2021.2.1 Beta 4
Build #AI-212.5712.43.2112.8233820, built on March 1, 2022
Runtime version: 11.0.12+0-b1504.28-7817840 x86_64
```

My compose version is `1.1.1`

---

Update 2:
I accept the answer from @MARSK. Just want to put more info at here for other buddy's information.

I was following the codepath this this [codelab](https://developer.android.com/codelabs/jetpack-compose-advanced-state-side-effects?authuser=1&continue=https%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.android.com%2Fcourses%2Fpathways%2Fcompose%3Fauthuser%3D1%23codelab-https%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.android.com%2Fcodelabs%2Fjetpack-compose-advanced-state-side-effects#3). So the code above was a part of it, the key point here I think is:

1. The key should be defined as a State, like `remember { mutableStateOf(1) }`
2. The expected result should be an infinite loop, because inside of the LaunchedEffect block, the statement key = 2 will always trigger a recomposition.

Why I wasn't able to figuring out how it works, and I got only 1 log print? That was because of the onTimeout callback, from parent level of LandingScreen composable, the function will remove this(LandingScreen) composable completely from the tree, thus it won't have any chance to be re-composed.

Comment: Have you tried running it on a physical device?

Comment: I tried on a physical first, then running it in emulator for screenshot. Running it again on my Samsung.

Comment: Same result: `2022-05-08 19:13:39.267 25012-25012/androidx.compose.samples.crane W/xx: Launched effect is running key with remember = 3`. on a physical device. Thanks.

Comment: I suggest you check out [this youtube video](https://youtu.be/mymWGMy9pYI) which explains the basic principles of state in Compose.

Comment: ok I will check it out. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var key by remember { mutableStateOf (1) }
```

The above is crucial for it to work. The code is working as expected. Here's the details.

When you run this simple code block

```
var key by remember { mutableStateOf(1) }
LaunchedEffect(key) {    
  Log.e("xx", "Running key $key")
  delay(2000)
  key = 2
}

key = 3
```

The code runs as: key is initialized to 1, and the effect runs for the value of `key = 1`, but, as correctly (I hope) pointed out by the OP in the comment below, `LaunchedEffect` takes a bit of a time to spawn a coroutine, which is enough for the control to shift to the next statement and alter the value of the key to be 3. This ensures that the value of key as 1 is never logged.

After this and a delay of two seconds, the value of the key changes to one, triggering an entire recomposition of the Composable, which means that the entire composable shall re-execute. Here's how that goes:

The key remains as 2, because we're using `remember`
LaunchedEffect gets called with a value of 2, but again, due to the coroutine-spawning time, the key is modified to be 3, WHICH, being different than 2, RE-TRIGGERS a recomposition, hence, never logging the 2, but only logging the 3, since that is what the value of `key` is now. Again, the previous `LaunchedEffect` is not cancelled, and when  its two-second delay is over, it will switch the value to `2` again, which immediately shifts back to `3` because of this composition. Hence, you'll get logs of `Running 3` consistently, with two logs occurring very close together in time, while the next on will be separated by a two-second interval.

This is what you get

```
17:28:43.241 : Running key 3
17:28:43.269 : Running key 3
17:28:45.298 : Running key 3
17:28:45.318 : Running key 3
17:28:47.356 : Running key 3
17:28:47.374 : Running key 3
17:28:49.422 : Running key 3
17:28:49.443 : Running key 3
17:28:51.501 : Running key 3
17:28:51.534 : Running key 3
17:28:53.591 : Running key 3
17:28:53.607 : Running key 3
17:28:55.649 : Running key 3
17:28:55.689 : Running key 3
```

Now, if you wish to correctly log the value with which the effect was called, you need to store it at the entry point itself. Like so,

```
var key by remember { mutableStateOf(1) }
var keyStore: Int
LaunchedEffect(key.also { keyStore = key }) {
    "Running key $keyStore".log()
    delay(2000)
    key = 2
}
key = 3
```

This produces the correct runtime logs

```
17:34:13.790 : Running key 1
17:34:13.821 : Running key 3
17:34:15.847 : Running key 2
17:34:15.862 : Running key 3
17:34:17.903 : Running key 2
17:34:17.922 : Running key 3
17:34:19.982 : Running key 2
17:34:20.015 : Running key 3
17:34:22.055 : Running key 2
17:34:22.073 : Running key 3
17:34:24.135 : Running key 2
17:34:24.154 : Running key 3
```

Comment: What's the output? It's not likely at all. Make sure you're installing the correcr version of the app. Studio has this bug that sometimes keeps installing the same version even after code modifications. Rebuild, or restart if need be.

Comment: It is the same as without having `remember { mutableStateOf(1) }`.  I wish I could send a screen recording to you.

`2022-05-08 18:53:50.953 22165-22165/androidx.compose.samples.crane W/xx: Launched effect is running key = 3`

Comment: Symptoms are installation within 3 seconds.

Comment: Hi @MARSK, I attached a screenshot in the post. TBH, I actually had tried myself by including `remember { mutableStateOf(1) }` before posting this question. 
When getting your answer, I believed it could be the reason, so I tried once again, but no, it didn't work. I took out the `remember {mutableStateOf(1)}` from the code snippet in my post that is because I read the documentation in `Effects.kt` Line 332 LaunchedEffect(key1: Any?), and the google's doc, neither mentioned the keys need to be put into a State. Thanks.

Comment: And as far as I could tell, the first print is 3 rather than 1, it could because the LaunchEffect will start a new coroutine, it takes some millseconds to finish that, but at the meanwhile, the next line, key = 3 finishes running, so when the LaunchEffect starts running the block, the key's value is 3. I think it'd work like this, but I don't feel this result fits the documentation correctly. Thus I asked.

Comment: `Studio has this bug that sometimes keeps installing the same version even after code modifications. Rebuild, or restart if need be.` -- Thanks. I cleaned and rebuilt, still the same result. I am using Android Studio Chipmunk | 2021.2.1 Beta 4
Build #AI-212.5712.43.2112.8233820, built on March 1, 2022

Comment: With the code i suggested, we get an infinite loop, as expected. You never told me ou got one. What if YOU are the bug? Why wouldn't you tell me such an important detail? Ok, game over buddy, it's time to de-bug reality. Run!

Comment: Yep, I patched up reality, I thought.... It was already ok, just needed observations. There you have it, anyway.

Comment: `we get an infinite loop, as expected.` -- my bad, I didn't realize this myself, and this is one of the key points to me for figuring out how it works. I didn't get an infinite loop because there is a callback: onTimeout, and in the callback I updated the outer state and the Composable of LandingScreen will be totally removed from the tree, thus I only saw one print which was 3. But I appreciate your explanation very much for how the key = 2 triggers the LandingScreen gets recomposed over and over again, it helps me a lot for understanding the State. Thank you again buddy!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/244591/discussion-between-liuwenbin-no-and-marsk).